# D3 - How can I handle null or empty values from an API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a stack barchart that loads in data from an API that uses this JSON format

```
    {
  value: data.source["1"]
},
{
  value: data.source["2"]
},
{
  value: data.source["3"]
},
{
  value: data.source["4"]
},
{
  value: data.source["5"]
},
{
  value: data.source["6"]
}
```

unfortunately, sometimes the API callback reads like this:

```
{
  value: data.source["1"]
},
{
  value: data.source["3"]
},
{
  value: data.source["5"]
}
```

Which leaves some entries undefined and breaks my vis.

How can I handle null values in key-value pairs so that my vis doesn't bread due to undefined? It would be great if I can get null values read as 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In frontend in the callbacks where you take the data from JSON you should wrap everything in (value: data.source["1"] || [])

something like this:

```
const data = jsonResponse.value.etc... || []
```

if it's falsy replace it with an empty array